# Showing that $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$ for $c\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$, $c$ nonzero

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

The problem is:

> Suppose $c\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0}$ for some nonzero scalar $c$. Show that $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$.

Using the axioms for a vector space, I figured I could use $c(d\mathbf{u}) = (cd)\mathbf{u}$ first, and multiplying both sides with the inverse of $c$: $$\begin{align}  c\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0} \\  c^{-1}(c\mathbf{u})=\mathbf{0} c^{-1} \\ (c^{-1}c)\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0} \\ 1\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0} \end{align}$$

And then use the axiom that $1 \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{u}$ to show that $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0}$.

Is this somewhat correct? Is there a better, or more precise way of doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the definition of a vector space, you may need to explain why $c^{-1}0=0$ (which is used on the RHS of the third line of your proof). In many (or most?) textbook definitions of a vector space, that "*the scalar multiple of a zero vector is the zero vector itself*" is not part of the definition, but a consequence of the axioms.